# Express body parser Dropping some of the Body content from httpRequest

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, node-modules

I have created a NodeJS API using Express and http module, so there are 2 end points listening on NodeJS API, one configured using express and other configured using http.
both the NodeJS API is called from a php application with the same post request.

it is observed that the body of the http request received by the 'express' module is missing some of the encoded data compared to the httprequest received by the 'http' module.

Following is the **http request** received by

**'express' module**

`AUTH_ID=646de4600055bddb79100000004282303ce34b89826f497664cc7b454dc1cb09a&AUTH_EXPIRES=360&REFRESH_ID=54ec0b6100d03004db79100000004282303549999a814f7edb267d2b6d76ed64&member_id=62bf3f572a96744f65c1cd8c8b14d&status=L&PLACEMENT=DEFAULT`

**'http' module**

`event=ONAPPINSTALL&data%5BVERSION%5D=1&data%5BLANGUAGE_ID%5D=en&ts=1625662649&auth%5Baccess_token%5D=c9b2e5600055bd0300b791000000040000038c866815aca87280645df4ff27dc5b3f&auth%5Bexpires%5D=1625666249&auth%5Bexpires_in%5D=3600&auth%5Bscope%5D=crm%2Cimbot%2Ctask%2Ctasks_extended%2Cimopenlines%2Cim&auth%5Bdomain%5D=debit24.in&auth%5Bserver_endpoint%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fth.bitrix.info%2Frest%2F&auth%5Bstatus%5D=L&auth%5Bclient_endpoint%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fbitrix24.in%2Frest%2F&auth%5Bmember_id%5D=63f572a98356744f65c1cd8c8b14d&auth%5Buser_id%5D=4&auth%5Brefresh_token%5D=b9310d0055bd004db791000000040000032cb18a48093e3a08d0f784e4b4297f&auth%5Bapplication_token%5D=118bb34acf0e9a231a6cfbe1e5221`

if you look at the above request the event and some other form data is missing and is not correctly parsed by the 'express' module. Is this an issue with express body parser, has any one encountered any similar issues.

by the way, the http request content-type send by the php code is x-www-form-urlencoded.

on the nodeJs side i am using the following express code

`app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false, limit:"500kb"}));`